# Let $T$ be a linear operator. Show $(I-T)^2 = I - T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm a bit lost here.

$(I-T)^2 = (I-T)(I-T) = (I-T) - T(I-T) = I-2T + T^2$

How is $T^2 - 2T + I = I - T$ ?

Comment: It isn't. You must be missing other conditions from the problem.

Comment: The claim is equivalent to $T^2=T$

Comment: @NinadMunshi No. My problem set must have a typo.

Answer (score 1):

It's understandable that you struggle because it's not true! For $T=0.5 I$ the LHS equals $0.25 I$ and the RHS equals $0.5I$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement above only holds if $T$ is idempotent that is $TT=T$. There may be some missing information in the problem. If $T$ is idempotent then $I-T$ is also idempotent and $(I-T)^2=(I-T)$